# session_start() and $_SESSION array, and match login to object in array

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am trying to get the login processor to match what the user types in, with the hard coded object array that contains the first name, last name, and password. I am not sure how to make the check between the login and the object array. I have 3 pages, the student.class.php, login.php, and processor.php.

I also need to use the  session_start() and $_SESSION array but I am not sure how to implement this into my project. would I make a seperate session file, or include it into my processor.

Student.class.php

```
<?php

class Student 
{

    private $f_name;
    private $l_name;
    private $full_name;
    private $password;

    //Constructor method
    public function __construct($f_name,$l_name,$password) {
        $this->f_name = $f_name;
        $this->l_name = $l_name; 
        $this->password = $password;
    }



    function get_name(){
        $full_name = $this->f_name.' '.$this->l_name;
        return $full_name;
    }

    function get_level(){
        return $this->level;
    }

    function get_gender(){
        return $this->gender;
    }

    function get_password(){
        return $this->password;
    }
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php

    require_once 'student.class.php';

    $students = array();

    $students[0] = new Student('Trey', 'Smith', 'senior', 'male', 'sailor1234');
    $students[1] = new Student('Kyle', 'McAulay', 'junior', 'male', 'abc123');
    $students[2] = new Student('Stacey', 'Keibler','senior','female', 'hotdawg23');
    $students[3] = new Student('Lindsey', 'Mullins', 'junior','female','gonoles69');
    $students[4] = new Student('Kenneth', 'Jaggers','senior', 'male', 'peterpanpan');
    $students[5] = new Student('Chad', 'Endris', 'sophomore', 'male','back2thefuture');

    ?>

    <h1>Sign up for our site!</h1>
    <form method="post" action="processor.php">     
        <fieldset>          
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name"/>

            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name"/>

            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password"/>                    
        </fieldset>

        <br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></input></br>
     </body>
</html>
```

processor.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

    require_once 'student.class.php';
    require_once 'login.php';

    function check_submit($field_to_check)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$field_to_check]) && $_POST[$field_to_check] != '')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Please fill in the $field_to_check category!";
        }
    }


    $errors = array();

    $_POST['first_name'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['first_name']));
    $_POST['last_name'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['last_name']));
    $_POST['password'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));


    if (check_submit('first_name') !== TRUE)
    {
        $errors[] = check_submit('first_name');
    }

    if (check_submit('last_name') !== TRUE)
    {
        $errors[] = check_submit('last_name');    
    }

    if (check_submit('password') !== TRUE)
    {
        $errors[] = check_submit('password');    
    }

    if (count($errors)> 0){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($errors as $message){
        echo "<li>$message</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";

    die();
    }

    ?>

    <h1>Thank you for registering <?php echo $_POST['first_name']."
    ".$_POST['last_name']?>!</h1>
    <h2>Your password was correct!</h2>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put session_start() at the top of any page you need to set/retrieve session data

Upon login submission, loop through your students array, testing each one against your $_POST inputs. If you get a match, save the object to a session variable such as $_SESSION['student']

```
foreach ($students as $student) {

    if ($student->f_name == $_POST['f_name'] &&
        $student->l_lame == $_POST['l_lame'] &&
        $student->password == $_POST['password'] ) {

        $_SESSION['student'] = $student;
        break;

    }

}
```

This isn't a great way to do this.. ideally you wouldn't be instantiating a new object for every student unless you're going to use all of them later.

Also, on processor.php, you're looking for $_POST['first_name'], but the name of the input field is 'f_name'

Comment: I just noticed f_name, l_name, etc are private. Is that necessary? If so, you'll have to either pass them out of the object or put the log-in checker as a method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the hard coded array should be in processor.php where you actually check user credentials, not in login.php, which just renders the login form. Then you should somehow traverse the array of students and check if what the user typed in is valid. But first let's add a handy little function to Student.php

```
class Student {
    function checkCredentials($firstname, $lastname, $password) {
        $firstname = strip_tags(trim($firstname));
        $lastname  = strip_tags(trim($lastname));
        $password  = strip_tags(trim($password));

        if(
            $this->f_name == $firstname
            && $this->l_name == $lastname
            && $this->password == $password
        ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;       
    }
}
```

Notice that I've moved input sanitization into the class. And we can now change processor.php a bit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

    function check_submit($field_to_check)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$field_to_check]) && $_POST[$field_to_check] != '')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Please fill in the $field_to_check category!";
        }
    }

    if (check_submit('first_name') !== TRUE)
    {
        $errors[] = check_submit('first_name');
    }

    if (check_submit('last_name') !== TRUE)
    {
        $errors[] = check_submit('last_name');    
    }

    if (check_submit('password') !== TRUE)
    {
        $errors[] = check_submit('password');    
    }


    if (count($errors)> 0){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($errors as $message){
            echo "<li>$message</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";       
        die();
    }               

    // so far we've only checked if the post values exist

    require_once "student.class.php";

    $students = array();

    $students[0] = new Student('Trey', 'Smith', 'senior', 'male', 'sailor1234');
    $students[1] = new Student('Kyle', 'McAulay', 'junior', 'male', 'abc123');
    $students[2] = new Student('Stacey', 'Keibler','senior','female', 'hotdawg23');
    $students[3] = new Student('Lindsey', 'Mullins', 'junior','female','gonoles69');
    $students[4] = new Student('Kenneth', 'Jaggers','senior', 'male', 'peterpanpan');
    $students[5] = new Student('Chad', 'Endris', 'sophomore', 'male','back2thefuture');

    $user = false; // Will store the logged in user, if login succeeds

    // Here we traverse the array and checkCredentials for each stored Student object
    foreach($students as $student) {

        if($student->checkCredentials($_POST["first_name"], $_POST["last_name"], $_POST["password"]) {                      
            $user = $student;
            break; // Since there can be only one logged in user, there is no point to let foreach continue
        }
    }

    if($user == false) {
        echo "No such user exits";
        die();
    }                           

    ?>

    <h1>Thank you for registering <?php echo $user->get_name; ?> !</h1> 
    <h2>Your password was correct!</h2>

    </body>
</html>
```

The most common approach for a successful login is store some kind of identifying user information (more commonly a userID) into a session variable, and redirect to the protected page. Since this is not possible with your hard coded array I'll just put the whole object in session. That's extremely crude and unsafe, you should really think about adding a database to the mix.

Let's call that page admin.php and the end of processor.php becomes:

```
    if($user == false) {
        echo "No such user exits";
        die();
    }                           

    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;

    header("Location: admin.php");
    die();
```

admin.php should look something like:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once "student.class.php";   

if(
    !isset($_SESSION["user"])
    || !( $_SESSION["user"] instanceof Student)
) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    die();
}

$user = $_SESSION["user"];  

?>

<h1>Thank you for registering <?php echo $user->get_name; ?> !</h1> 
<h2>Your password was correct!</h2>
```

So what happens here is:

- session_start() tells php you want to use sessions, and it should be in every script that uses them, before you output anything to the screen (i.e. at the very top of the script, before any html). You should also put it in processor.php
- before allowing the user to do anything in admin.php we check if the $_SESSION["user"] variable has been initialised and if it holds a Student object
- if not we sent the user back to login.
- if yes we put the Student object into a nice variable to play around with.

Comment: everything has worked amazingly, but i cannot get the admin.php header to redirect me to the admin.php page. it just reloads the login.php page like nothing happened.

Comment: Does processor.php have session_start() at the top of it?